# Salesforce 24 Hour Limits Reset Time

Tags: limits

The SF limits are said to reset every 24 hours - how do I know when exactly? 
Is it on some constant time of day for all the orgs, or based on the org time zone?

For example - if I have crossed the callout limit, when will it be reset and I would be able to callout again?

Answer (score 7):

The e-mail limits are calculated based on Greenwich Mean Time - see "Email Limits" in http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

I think other limits are calculated on a 24-hour basis, but I'm not 100% certain. I don't believe limits are ever "reset" to 0. We've watched our API usage at my company, and we noticed them fluctuating throughout the day.

Also from the documentation above: "The maximum number of batch executions is 250,000 per 24 hours." The language used (*Per 24 hours*) seems to indicate an on-going basis.

Comment: This is what I've always been lead to believe as well.  API calls for instance are "last 24 hours" for certain (if you are nearing your limits and/or have the warnings being sent to you, this relays this fact pretty clearly).

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is cumulative over a given 24 hour period rather than being set at specific points in time, i.e. between 00:00 and 23:59. I think it checks the preceding 24 hours to see how many callouts have been made in that time period, and if you've exceeded the limit it will raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it checks this time based on the org's timezone?

Comment: Of course I don't know for sure (the docs are a little vague) but I *think* it just checks the preceding 24 hours of activity

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering as well and checked with the Salesforce Support team - it's a 24h sliding window.

You can take it quite literally as exactly “the last 24 hours”.

I wrote a short post about this here:
https://mbwhatsnew.wordpress.com/2017/07/10/when-does-the-salesforce-api-limit-reset/